# Fetching data not showing in frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data from a backend to frontend, the data is fetching fine, and showing in console log, but it's not showing in front end

[image]

The Code:

```
export default function ShopPage() {

  const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
  
  const [shop, setShop] = useState("");
  const shopName = useParams().shopName;

  const [shopCoupons, setCoupons] = useState([]);

  const { search } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchShop = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(`/shops/${shopName}`);
      setShop(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    };
    fetchShop();
  }, [shopName]);
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchShopCoupons = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`/coupons/${shopName}`);
      setCoupons(response.data);
      console.log("Shop Coupons are:", response.data);
    
    };
    fetchShopCoupons();
  }, [shopName]);
  
  return (
    <>
        <Box>
          <Stack>
        <Box >

        {shopCoupons.map(c => (
            
            <Coupon coupon={c} />
            
        ))}

        </Box>
        </Stack>
        </Box>
        
    </>
  )
}
```

I think the problem is in `shopCoupons.map` I don't know what i'm missing here

Coupon Component:

```
export default function Coupon({ coupon }) {

    const start = moment();
      const end = moment(coupon.validTill, 'DD MM YYYY');
      const diff = end.diff(start, "days")

       if (diff >= 0 ) {
  return (
    <div className="coupon-container">
    <div className="coupon">
          <div className="co-img">
            {coupon.photo && 
            <img className="couponLogo"
            src={coupon.photo} alt="" />}
          </div>
        <div className="content">
          <h2>{coupon.shopName}</h2>
          <h1>{coupon.title}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="couponDesc">
          {coupon.desc}
        </div>
        <div className="coupon-row">
          <span id="cpnCode">{coupon.coupon}</span>
        <div className="bottom-row">
          <div className="couponValidity">
          <p></p> 
          </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
    </div>

  );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
}
```

this is what the page should show an array of this component, i get the data in console log but it's not fetching to frontend

Comment: You are using `useEffect` twice and I'm pretty sure that it can't work this way...

Comment: your question is not clear. what is not showing? you get any errors or you render nothing?

Comment: What does your `Coupon` component look like?

Comment: can you show us the coupon component ?

Comment: @VersifiXion i edited the question please have a look

Comment: If the data isn't showing, it could be that IF statement you have in the Coupon Component, I'd try seeing what it evaluates to in a console.log before the IF condition.

Comment: @QueensCoder that if statement is for the date, if it's previous date it will not show i tried to remove it but it didn't work also

Answer (score 0):

First off lets just add a key, it looks like what you're iterating over has an `id` variable so

```
   {shopCoupons.map(c =>
        <Coupon id={c.id} coupon={c}
    ))}
```

Should work out okay.
With moment you've got

```
const end = moment(coupon.validTill, 'DD MM YYYY');
```

I forget the API but that doesn't look right as `'DD MM YYYY'` would typically format it whereas you're still trying to do logic on it, so get rid of that and format it with `.format("DD MM YYYY")`

Also it doesn't appear that shop has any use as a string, maybe just give it nothing so it's undefined and not tricking a reader into thinking it's going to remain a string in its lifetime.

```
const [shop, setShop] = useState();
```

I'm wondering if your `moment` logic is causing the `else` condition to run all the time, should really just replace null with something like `<p> No data or error</p>` so it's a bit more obvious you've reached that point and there isn't some other React bug going on.